# rails4: Image_tag defaultaly generating cludinary urls and not localhost url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am using Cloudinary with my rails4 project. So far everything was working so well. But I am facing one issue while loading static assets from /assets/images directory.

I am having 'sample.png' image file in "assets/images" directory. And in my view I am trying to load image using following tag.

```
<%= image_tag('sample.png') %>
```

But as Cloudinary also have image_tag, this is looking to load image 'sample.png' from Cloudinary and not from 'assets/images' directory.

The above image tag is generating below img tag in view

```
<img alt="sample.png" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/ACCOUNT_NAME/image/asset/sample.png">
```

My question is how can I make image_tag to load assets from "/assets/images" directory ?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you set [enhance_image_tag](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_image_manipulation#enhanced_image_tag) in your config? Looks like otherwise you would need to use `cl_image_tag` to get that

Comment: Yes, I did set enhance_image_tag to true in my cloudinary.yml file. But to use rails standard image_tag we also have to set 'static_image_support' to true. Which was false earlier, setting both options true did the job.